# General covariance and global Poincaré algebras

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, poincare-symmetry, diffeomorphism-invariance

Reading an [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410046) (page 7) I read this:

> *Just as ordinary general covariance may be regarded as the local gauge
>   symmetry corresponding to the global Poincare algebra and local gauge invariance as the gauge symmetry corresponding to the global abelian algebra*

I would like if somebody could tell me with as much detail as possible the relation between general covariance and a global Poincaré algebra.